Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.Booster
Spark Version: 3.0
xgboost4j_2.12-1.7.1
when using scala train xgboost model, I got a error :
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Exception while getting task result: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.Booster
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2173)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2121)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2119)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2119)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1046)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1046)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1046)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2357)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2303)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2292)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:842)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2439)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2460)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2479)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2504)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1019)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:393)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1018)
  at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$.trainDistributed(XGBoost.scala:414)
  at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostClassifier.train(XGBoostClassifier.scala:202)
  at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostClassifier.train(XGBoostClassifier.scala:34)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:150)
  ... 37 elided
UsageError: Scala Execution Failed

Scala
I used the different xgboost4j version through the sc.addjar() ,but got the same error.
